# Jupiterlab inline plot

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-lab

The code below was executed in notebook opened in **Jupyter Lab** (not Jupiter notebook), but it didn't show the plot.

Does anyone else have this problem? Did you need to run special command to enable inline plotting in **Jupyter Lab**?

input:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6),facecolor="white",dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
plt.show()
```

output: `FigureCanvasNbAgg()`.

Comment: I *think* (because I haven't tested) that you set a backend just the way you do it with a notebook, i.e. `%matplotlib inline`. Possibly also `%matplotlib ipympl`.

Comment: With "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt", no problem for me.

Comment: I am having this same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `%matplotlib inline` somewhere in the notebook and you should be fine